# One to one correspondence Why?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How does the definition of one to one correspondence imply all elements in the two sets can be paired with no remaining?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: That's the definition of 1 to 1 correspondence!

Comment: But how does this imply that all elements are paired?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to know how a function is bijective iff it is both surjective and injective?

Comment: No, let's just not mention the function please. I am trying to gain a intuitive poof.

Comment: You may need to tell us your definition of a one to one correspondence then.

Comment: My definition is that all elements in the sets can be perfectly paired with each other with no remainder

Comment: Then I don't understand what's missing from the two answers? They show that given a correspondence, you can think about it as a function, as a set of ordered pairs which define a bijection. ORDERED PAIRS. BIJECTION. Those are the keywords you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Given that for every elements in A, there is exactly one element in B corresponds to it. And for every elements in B, there is exactly one element in A corresponds to it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you are right. I do understand it in the point of view of function. But it seems like this concept is intuitive to many people, is there a more intuitive way to explain this?

Comment: I'm really not sure what else you might want to hear. Would you prefer it if I rewrote my answer in words, without using "ordered pair"? I can do that, mechanically. I could write a simple program to do it for me, too. So there's nothing to gain or lose by this sort of translation. Only that it won't be using the notion of an ordered pair. Which is a bit strange if you want to think about pairings.

Comment: No, that's fine. Thank you so much for your time. I think I will just have to think about it more.

Comment: Here's a problem that may help: Count the number of three letter sequences such that it is in alphabetical order. To solve this, we create a bijection from the set of three letter sequences in alphabetical order and the set of all combinations of 3 letters. The bijection is somewhat obvious. Each 3 letter sequence can be mapped to a combination. Each combination can be mapped to a 3 letter sequence by arranging it in alphabetical order. So we use this bijection to see that the order of the two sets are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to prove that there exists a perfect pairing of elements from $A$ to $B$. The pairing you want is given by
$$\{(a,b)\in A\times B\mid b\text{ corresponds to }a\}$$
The properties of 1 to 1 correspondence say exactly what you want. In fact, this is the usual definition of a function in the set theory  which corresponds to the bijection you have between $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a correspondence like that, consider the set $$\{\langle a,b\rangle\mid a\in A\text{ and }b\text{ is the element corresponding to }a\}.$$

Every element of $A$ appears in exactly one pair in the left coordinate; and every element of $B$ appears in exactly one pair in the right coordinate. So this is exactly what you have there.

Answer (score 0):

A one-to-one correspondence is given by an injective function. An injective function does not necessarily map elements of its domain to every of element of its codomain.  See [Bijection, injection and surjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection)

Perhaps you are thinking of a bijection.

**EDIT:**

To prove that there exists a bijection between sets $A$ and $B$, you have at least two options:

1. Prove there exists $f:A\to B$ that is both injective and surjective.
2. Prove there exists $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ were both are injective. (See [Cantor–Bernstein-Schröder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem))

Comment: In the second option, I think it suffices to prove there exists $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$

Comment: And then we can think this way, let an element $a$ in $A$ be given. It must then corresponds to an element in $B$ since $f:A\rightarrow B.$ Now, the element in $B$ must correspond to one and only one element in $A$ as $f:B\rightarrow A$. And more specifically, it must correspond to $a$ since correspondence it a two way relationship. Now these two elements are paired and will not appear again. In this way, all element in $A$ is paired with a distinct element in $B$. To see all element in $B$ are used up(all paired off), we can again let an element $b$ in $B$ be given and then proceed as before.

Comment: See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

one to one correspondence is of course Bijective, after you have grasp t[he definition of Surjection, Injection and Bijection](http://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/injective-surjective-bijective.html), then you will get the answer to your question.